# Connection limt reached issue [C014] in Attunity

Tags: c#, connection-pooling, attunity

I have a project that connects to a RMS file system through Attunity (Version 1.0.0.8). The RMS file is in a different server. The connection pool on both client and service is 10 (Max connection pool size). When we hit the server from the client, we sometimes get the error:

> C014: Client connection limit reached - try later.

I would like to understand whether this error is related to Server overloaded or any issues on the Client side. I am sure that the client code that I am using to connect to the server is properly opening and disposing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem we were having. We were running Attunity on OpenVms and we were maxing out the number of DECNET connections to Attunity between our nodes; the underlying problem was with our client. The clients in this case would induce a longstanding transaction or had problems releasing their connections back to the pool. We fixed the issue by eliminating the longstanding transactions and then finding the bug in the clients where the they would not release their connection. Unfortunately, all of our clients are implemented in Java and Cobol, so I don't have any .Net specific advice.